# Followed the exact code for Builder Pattern, but getting error

Tags: java

I tried building my own builder pattern after reading a popular blogpost, and an error came up so I thought I did something wrong. I double, triple checked my code but I kept getting the error. So I decided to copy the entire code from the blog and yet I'm still getting an error and I don't know why.

Code from the blogpost:

https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern

```
public class BankAccount {
    public static class Builder {
        private long accountNumber; //This is important, so we'll pass it to the constructor.
        private String owner;
        private String branch;
        private double balance;
        private double interestRate;
        public Builder(long accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }
        public Builder withOwner(String owner){
            this.owner = owner;
            return this;  //By returning the builder each time, we can create a fluent interface.
        }
        public Builder atBranch(String branch){
            this.branch = branch;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder openingBalance(double balance){
            this.balance = balance;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder atRate(double interestRate){
            this.interestRate = interestRate;
            return this;
        }
        public BankAccount build(){
            //Here we create the actual bank account object, which is always in a fully initialised state when it's returned.
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount();  //Since the builder is in the BankAccount class, we can invoke its private constructor.
            account.accountNumber = this.accountNumber;
            account.owner = this.owner;
            account.branch = this.branch;
            account.balance = this.balance;
            account.interestRate = this.interestRate;
            return account;
        }
    }
    //Fields omitted for brevity.
    private BankAccount() {
        //Constructor is now private.
    }
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"Fields omitted for brevity"* but the **error** is that those fields apparently don't exist! If you omit them from your code then what are we supposed to do?

Comment: Don't post images of code or errors. You may want to review [ask] to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the fields on the `BankAccount` class, only on the `Builder`. There is a comment in the article, where they implemented the builder, that says "Fields omitted for brevity". You'll need to follow the first example where they have:

```java
public class BankAccount {
    private long accountNumber;
    private String owner;
    private String branch;
    private double balance;
    private double interestRate;
    public BankAccount(long accountNumber, String owner, String branch, double balance, double interestRate) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
   }
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Then you'll need to create the getters and setters, and call the setters from the `Builder`, such as:

```java
public class BankAccount {
    //...

    public void setAccountNumber(long value) {
        this.accountNumber = value;
    }

    // In the Builder
    account.setAccountNumber(this.accountNumber);
}
```